# How to do disconnect on UDP socket using boost::asio

Tags: udp, boost-asio

Combining the information from [boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/connect/overload1.html) and [manual for connect function](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect) I take it that the *asio::udp::socket::connect* function serves to set the address to which datagrams are sent by default, and the only address from which datagrams are received.

This works nicely but the manual also states that I should be able to dissolve the association (disconnect), which is what I'm having problem doing. I.e. I would like the socket to start receiving packets from any address again.

Further in the manual is written:

```
Connectionless sockets may dissolve the association by connecting to an
address with the sa_family member of sockaddr set to AF_UNSPEC.
```

I have tried this code:

```
asio::udp::endpoint unspecified_endpoint;
assert(unspecified_endpoint.address().is_unspecified()); // OK
socket.connect(unspecified_endpoint);
```

But that did not help.

---

EDIT: Created a test case by taking the [client](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/blocking_udp_echo_client.cpp) and [server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/blocking_udp_echo_server.cpp) examples from boost::asio page. In client code, I've changed the outgoing port number from random to 5192:

```
udp::socket s(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 5192));
```

And I changed the function *server* in the server code:

```
void server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
{
  udp::socket sock(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port));

#define CASE 3

#if CASE == 1
  sock.connect(udp::endpoint());
#elif CASE == 2
  sock.connect(udp::endpoint(ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 5193));
  sock.connect(udp::endpoint());
#elif CASE == 3
  sock.connect(udp::endpoint(ip::address::from_string("192.168.1.3"), 5192));
  sock.connect(udp::endpoint());
#endif

  for (;;)
  {
    char data[max_length];
    udp::endpoint sender_endpoint;
    size_t length = sock.receive_from(
    boost::asio::buffer(data, max_length), sender_endpoint);
    sock.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(data, length), sender_endpoint);
  }
}
```

Cases 1 and 2 seem to work, but in case 3 the client wont receive a reply. The full source can be found [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/81480906/udp_connect.tar.bz2).

Comment: The udp is not connection oriented.

Comment: @bbg, Indeed, but connecting is not what I'm trying to accomplish. It is a bit misleading that the function is called *connect* but all it does is set up a filter for the address of incoming and outgoing packets. What I'm having trouble with is removing this filter.

Comment: The boost asio code actually passes AF_INET with an unspecified IP address to connect (and not AF_UNSPEC), but this still appears to work on my Linux system. What OS are you using and can you post the code to a complete (minimal) example?

Comment: @cmeerw, I've added a test code example. I'm on linux with kernel 3.2.0. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the call to `sock.connect(udp::endpoint());` translates to `connect(6, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0` which isn't the same as a `connect` with `AF_UNSPEC` and doesn't completely disconnect the UDP socket (it appears to only reset the peer port number).

I don't think there is a way to achieve what you want purely with boost asio, but you could just use a native POSIX call to disconnect the socket, something like

```
struct sockaddr unspec_addr = { AF_UNSPEC };
::connect(sock.native_handle(), &unspec_addr, sizeof(unspec_addr));
```

Debugging notes: run the program with `strace` and then use `netstat -nu` to list the UDP sockets.

Answer (score 0):

To keep access to library functions, use the fact that `udp::endpoint` is just a wrapper around `sockaddr`. Construct `sockaddr` with a specific value and cast it to the required type.

```
sock.connect(reinterpret_cast<const udp::endpoint &>(static_cast<const sockaddr &>(sockaddr{ AF_UNSPEC })));
```